# How python deals with regular expressions like r'([abc])+'

Tags: python, regex

In python's doc, I see an example:

```
m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
m.groups() # ('c',)
```

How does that happen? I supposed the subgroup should be 'a'.

Comment: When a capturing group is repeated, it will return the last instance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the behaviour is unspecified. When you use a capture group within a repetition operator, it generally captures the last match. However, the discussion in [Python Issue 7132](http://bugs.python.org/issue7132) suggests that this is not always the case:

> Yes, but this is necessary for full consistency of the group indexes. 
>   The current return value is clearly inconsistant (generally it returns 
>   the last occurence of the capturing group, but I've discovered that this 
>   is not always the case, because of matches that are returned after 
>   backtracking...)

It is, however, easy to modify your example to return every character:

```
In [7]: m = re.match("([abc]+)", "abc") # a slightly different regex

In [8]: list(m.groups()[0])
Out[8]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Here, the entire sequence is captured as a single group and then split.

Comment: I get `['c']` in both Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3. Ah, you're using IronPython? Could it be that IPython uses the .NET regex engine internally? That would be a) unexpected and b) awesome because .NET is one of the few engines that allows access to individual captures of a repeated group.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Just to be clear, are you getting `['c']` with my code or OP's? My code produces `['a', 'b', 'c']` on CPython 2.7.3 (not tested with Python 3, but I'd expect it to do the same).

Comment: @NPE: The regex you are showing is weird. You are capturing the `[abc]+` (a sequence instead of single character like in the question), but you still get each separate character? EDIT: Nevermind, the `list()` will split up the string by character.

Comment: @NPE: I got confused a bit due to the discussion that Tim Pietzcker raised, but it turns out to be normal.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that you changed the regex. In effect, you did a `list("abc")`, so I was just as confused as nhahtdh.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: My apologies. I've added some comments to help avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
>>> m.group(0)
'abc'
>>> m.group(1)
'c'
>>> m.groups()
('c',)
```

The regex `([abc])+` matches the entire string (see `m.group(0)`).

This match is obtained by capturing a single character `[abc]`, capturing the result into group number 1, and then repeating the process. So that group will first be `a`, then (on the next repetition) `b`, and finally `c`.

`.groups()` returns a tuple of all the capturing group matches. Since there is only one capturing group, you get a one-element tuple.